# I Can't Animate With Linear Gradients

Tags: html, css, jquery-animate, linear-gradients

I made an **animation** that is supposed to have **Tilted & Jump** to another spot on the screen, but the gradient won't work at all.

I used this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    img {
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background: linear gradient(red,yellow);
      color: #ffffff;
      position: relative;
      font-weight:bold;
      font-size:20px;
      padding:10px;
      border-radius:5px;
      animation:animated_div 5s 5;
      -webkit-animation:animated_div 5s 1;
         -moz-animation:animated_div 5s 1;
           -o-animation:animated_div 5s 5;
                -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    }

    @keyframes animated_div {
      0% {transform: rotate(0deg);left:0px;}
      12.5% {transform: rotate(20deg);left:0px;}
      25% {transform: rotate(0deg);left:500px;}
      27.5% {transform: rotate(0deg);left:500px;}
      35% {transform: rotate(0deg);left:500px;background:-webkit- linear-    gradient(red,yellow;}
      50% {transform: rotate(-360deg);left:0px;}
      62.5% {transform: rotate(0deg);left:0px;}
      77.5% {transform: rotate(20deg);left:0px;}
      80% {transform: rotate(0deg);left:500px;}
      90% {transform: rotate(0deg);left:500px;}
      95% {transform: rotate(0deg);left:500px;background:-webkit-linear-    gradient(Yellow,Red;}
      100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);left:0px;}
    }
    body{background-color:black;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img class="q" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C3dJvIZUEAAkIjg.png">
</body>
</html>
```

But it won't change the border gradients likeI wanted.

Comment: First please correct all the typo errors in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a hyphen in `linear-gradient`.

That line should read:
`background: linear-gradient(red,yellow);`

Comment: i Tried It Before...It Did Not Work,But Is Now, You See THat The Tags Had The - So I Didn't Notice It,Thanks!